# Custom comments Java Eclipse editor templates

Tags: java, android, eclipse, templates, editor

I'm trying to customize templates to accelerate my Android and Java coding in Eclipse.
I use "Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Templates".

For example:
I want to write automatically this after braze in a private method:

```
// <nameOfTheMethod>()
```

The template original is like this:

```
private ${return_type} ${name}(${}) {
    ${cursor}
}
```

I override that in this way:

```
private ${return_type} ${name}(${}) {
    ${cursor}
} // ${name}(${})
```

But it doesn't work when I write a private method in my code. I try click and unclick "Automatically insert".

Comment: I explain me better... Actually this works if I write 'private' and then I push 'CTRL + Enter'. But I want to do automatically this comments in onCreate(), onCreateOptionsMenu(), etc at the moment I start a project.